# Jquery selector problem

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have two  in a table with ids row_26 and notificationrow_26. notificationrow_26 is dynamically added to DOM after page has been loaded.

I want to highlight notificationrow_26. So I use

```
var deviceUID = 26;
$("#notificationrow_" + deviceUID).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

but when I do this. It does not highlight that row. I also tried just accessing notificationrow_26 but it does not access that even.

It does highlight row_26 when I ask it to. I heard something about jquery live but how can I access it with jquery live? I think jquery live is only for events and stuff. I just want to access this row which has been added to DOM dynamically.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How about some more code? Does the newly-added row have a background-color? (It needs one for `highlight` to work, and the cells inside it need to *not* have a background to stop them obscuring the row background.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to invoke the .effect statement after you have added the elements to the DOM. You could use .live if you're attaching elements to DOM by 'click' or other common events ( not 'change' though, you'll need livequery for that ).

Comment: To clarify what meder is saying, when you first load the page jQuery will go through any element you've asked it to look out for or change, and will bind the actions to that element. So when you add things to the DOM after loading, jQuery doesn't recognise those new elements unless it is told about them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `.effect()`, is it a plugin or part of another JavaScript framework? The following code will highlight the row, providing that there are no conflicts with `$` shorthand on the page

```
var deviceUID = 26;
$("#notificationrow_" + deviceUID).css('background-color','highlight');
```

this can only be applied after the row has been inserted into the DOM (what I mean is that when the command is executed, it will only affect those elements that match the selector that exist in the DOM at the time).

So, depending on how the row is being added, you could add the highlighting in a callback function if there is one, chain the highlighting command onto the row before/immediately after it's inserted into the DOM. **[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/uzaxu)** to show the above code.